# Reusing; i.e., continuing in stream of a python data generator in a class

Tags: python, object, stream, generator

I wrote the following example class, which features a generator -- in this case a range object.

```
class tmp():

    def _setgen(self):
        self.gen = range(1,5)

    def __init__(self):
        self._setgen() # I define my generator only once; here in the __init__()

    def getval(self):

        for g in self.gen: # use the afore defined `gen`
            print(g)
            if g > 2:
                break


t = tmp() # init the object; including the range within the object

t.getval() # As expected numbers 1,2,3

t.getval() # Expect Number 4; but get again 1,2,3
```

Why is the range object resetted? I want to continue, where I stopped at the break.
So the second call of `t.getval()` should print a 4, and not operate on a new (?) range object from start again.

And what is a work around to get my "desired behaviour"?

Comment: "which features a generator -- in this case a range object." `range` objects are *not* generators. They aren't even iterators (to see for yourself, try `next(range(10))`. They are *iterables*, so each time you iterate over them, it uses a new, independent iterator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.gen = iter(range(1, 5))
```

would do the trick. `gen` should be the iterator over the `range` if you want to keep that as the state.

the `for` loop in your `getval` wraps the `range` in a fresh `iter` every time you call it.